# Cannot find gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am creating a Android Project in Intelli JIdea 13.0  from scratch. I need to build a simple Hello World Android Project.I have referenced the JDK 1.7 and Android SDK properly.
When i finish making the project using Wizard I get this message

*Could not save project!: Unable to save project files. Please ensure project files are writable and you have permissions to modify them. Try to save project again.*

*FileNotFoundException: C:.......\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties (The system cannot find the path specified): C:.......\gradle.*

Can anyone point where am i doing wrong?

PS. I tested making project on different locations on my drive but i get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I created the project, I had selected the template for "Gradle: Android Application", which has a dependency on Gradle (http://www.gradle.org/downloads).  If instead you create the project from one of the "Android templates" (e.g.: "Application module"), you won't get the error.